# how to customize the secondary highlighting in searches

Tags: isearch, emacs24

When I search for text in my buffer, the cursor moves to the first occurrence but *all* occurrences beyond the first are also lit. E.g. "jumped" in the screenshot below:

[image]

Unfortunately, this particular color for the "other" occurrences is very similar to a color used in my Java syntax highlighting and so I would like to customize it to make it stand out more (e.g. perhaps adding a background color too). What do I do that?

Comment: `M-x customize-face RET lazy-highlight RET`. Change it and save the change, using the `State` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the lazy-highlight face:

```el
(custom-set-faces
  `(lazy-highlight ((t (:foreground "white" :background "SteelBlue")))))
```

But this face is used in other cases.